# How many attacks does an Adaptive Shifter get when using the ranged ability from Spiked Form?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, attack, shapeshifting

The Adaptive Shifter Archetype can select a reactive form called Spiked Form, which when taken twice, grants the Shifter the ability to shoot their spines as a ranged thrown natural weapon multiple times.

> ...She can learn this form a second time, allowing her to fling her
>   spines as thrown natural weapons that deal piercing damage, have a
>   range increment of 30 feet, and allow her to make multiple attacks
>   with her spines as part of a full attack; these otherwise deal damage
>   and overcome damage reduction as her shifter claws.

The thing I'm confused on is how many attacks the shifter gets, because as I understand it, the number of natural attacks you can make in a full attack is limited by how many you have. Normally, I would think that this means that you could only attack once with the spines, but the text specifically calls out making multiple attacks with the spines.

The two suggestions I've seen (from only one person, there doesn't seem to be a lot on this) are either only getting 2 attacks from the spines (since normally you'd only have two claw attacks, on which the damage is based, except that Adaptive Shifter can change their two claws into one bite, gore, or tail slap) or that it's based on BAB iterative attacks (except that normally natural attacks don't interact with BAB). Like, currently it seems like RAW is as many attacks as you have spines, which is ridiculous as it calls out spines all over your body in the first half of the description. Any thoughts...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A shifter can make iterative attacks as they would with a manufactured weapon

During a full attack, you can normally make one attack for each natural weapon that you have. However, shifters gain the *Shifter's Fury* class feature.

> **Shifter's Fury** (Ex): At level 6, a shifter gains the ability to make several ferocious attacks with the same natural weapon. Instead of attacking with all her natural weapons, the shifter can choose a single natural weapon and make a full attack with that natural weapon, gaining a second iterative attack at a –5 as if it was a manufactured weapon. When she does so, all her other natural attacks count as secondary attacks and don't benefit from shifter's claws. At 11th level, she gains a third iterative attack at a –10 and at 16th level, she gains a fourth iterative attack at –15.

Since the spines are listed as thrown natural weapons, they also qualify for Shifter's Fury and you can make iterative attacks with them.